# Replace text from select statement from one file to another

Tags: sql, loops, select, for-loop, sed

I have a bunch of views for my database and need to update the select statements within each view.

I have all the select statements in files called *viewname.txt* in one dir and in a sub dir called sql; I have the all the views *viewname.sql*.  I want to run a script to take the text from *viewname.txt* and replace the select statement in the correct *viewname.sql* in the sql sub dir.

I have tried this to append the text after the SELECT in each .sql file:

```
for i in */*; do
  if ["../$(basename "${i}")" == "$(basename "${i}")"]
  then
    sed '/SELECT/a "$(basename "$i" .txt)"' "$(basename "$i" .sql)"
  fi
done
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Dickie

Comment: turn on shell debugger with `set -vx` and you should see an obvious logic error in your `if` test. Also might want to read about `HERE` documents, using `sed <<-EOS #sed_cmds without the single quotes .... EOS` you could use `cat $viewname.txt` inside the `HERE` document (I'm pretty sure). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an awk answer that's close - the output is placed in the sql directory under corresponding "viewname.sql.new" files.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# absorb the whole viewname.txt file into arr when the first line is read
FILENAME ~ /\.txt$/ && FILENAME != last_filename {
    last_filename = FILENAME

    # get the viewname part of the file name
    split( FILENAME, file_arr, "." )

    while( getline file_data <FILENAME > 0 ) {
        old_data = arr[ file_arr[ 1 ] ]
        arr[ file_arr[ 1 ] ] = \
            old_data (old_data == "" ? "" : "\n") file_data
    }
    next
}

# process each line of the sql/viewname.sql files
FILENAME ~ /\.sql$/ {
    # strip the "/sql" from the front of FILENAME for lookup in arr
    split( substr( FILENAME, 5 ), file_arr, "." )
    if( file_arr[ 1 ] in arr ) {
        if( $0 ~ /SELECT/ )
            print arr[ file_arr[ 1 ] ] > FILENAME ".new"
        else
            print $0 > FILENAME ".new"
    }
}
```

I put this into a file called `awko` and `chmod +x` and ran it like the following

```
awko *.txt sql/*
```

You'll have to mv the new files into place, but it's as close as I can get right now.